# Fading out, then fading in new content with jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I've been trying to get this thing to work for a while, and I'm having a problem. While testing offline, the content of a div properly fades out, then the new content fades in from a different HTML. Now, when it's live on the internet, the content fades out, then the same content fades in again, and only then it just gets updated with new content. Like it's lagging or something, but I'm sure that's not the case

Here's the javascript code I used to do it:

```
$(function() {
    $("#one").click(function() {
        $("#content").fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $("#content").load('main.html').fadeIn('slow');
        });         
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Move the `fadeIn` code inside the load `callback` like below,

```
$(function() {
    $("#one").click(function() {
        $("#content").fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $("#content").load('main.html', function () {
                 $(this).fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });         
    });
});
```

What could be happening is that the load is taking more time to get `main.html` (coz of n/w) but your `fadeIn` kicks in before that.. so moving `.fadeIn` inside `.load` callback should fix that problem.

Perhaps you should add a status message if `.load` is taking more time.. Try something like below..

```
            $("#content")
                  .html('<b>Loading.. Please wait...</b>')
                  .load('main.html', function () {
                      $(this).fadeIn('slow');
                  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am just tired and did the same as you told me here now, but I typed "fadeIn('slow');" instead of "$(this).fadeIn('slow');". I knew it was supposed to be fading in as a callback function, but I typed it out wrong, heh.